# Why does my Q chained promise rejection not behave the way I expect?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, promise, q

What am I doing wrong here?  I have a piece of code that looks something like this:

```
function getUserList(requestingUserId){
  return customerRepo.getCustomersAllowedByUser(requestingUserId)
  .then(function(customers){
    return userRepo.getUserList({customers: customers});
  });
}
```

my repository code is stubbed out like this:

```
customerDeferred = q.defer();
userDeferred = q.defer();

customerRepository.getCustomersAllowedByUser = sinon.stub().returns(customerDeferred.promise);
userRepository.getUsers = sinon.stub().returns(userDeferred.promise);
```

It all works fine when both promises are resolved, and as expected when I reject the customer promise, however when I resolve the customer promise and reject the user promise the test breaks down.  Here is the test:

```
it('should forward the rejection when userRepository rejects the promise', function(done){
  var rejectionError = new Error("test");
  var receivedError;

  userServices.getUserList(1)
  .then(null, function(error){
    receivedError = error;
  })
  .fin(function(){
    receivedError.should.equal(rejectionError);
    done();
  });

  customerDeferred.resolve(customerList);
  userDeferred.reject(rejectionError);
});
```

Comment: How does it break down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what's wrong, replace your test temporarily with just:

```
var rejectionError = new Error("test");
var receivedError;

userServices.getUserList(1).done();

customerDeferred.resolve(customerList);
userDeferred.reject(rejectionError);
```

This will print out the actual error.  Once you've fixed all the errors that just result from typos, you'll find that it works.

The problem is that `userRepo` is different from `userRepository` and `getUsers` is different from `getUserList`.

Having fixed all these I ended up with:

```
var q = require('q')
var sinon = require('sinon')

var assert = require('assert')

customerDeferred = q.defer();
userDeferred = q.defer();

var customerList = []
var customerRepo = {}
var userRepo = {}

customerRepo.getCustomersAllowedByUser = sinon.stub().returns(customerDeferred.promise);
userRepo.getUsers = sinon.stub().returns(userDeferred.promise);

function getUserList(requestingUserId){
  return customerRepo.getCustomersAllowedByUser(requestingUserId)
  .then(function(customers){
    return userRepo.getUsers({customers: customers});
  });
}

var rejectionError = new Error("test");
var receivedError;

getUserList(1)
.then(null, function(error){
  receivedError = error;
})
.fin(function(){
  assert.equal(receivedError, rejectionError);
  console.log('DONE')
});

customerDeferred.resolve(customerList);
userDeferred.reject(rejectionError);
```

Which runs perfectly.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out right after I posted.  Thanks for the tip on .done()